# Missing SRV Records

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to replicate a Server 2016 domain controller.  It appears to complete correctly, everything looks good in AD UC and AD SS with no errors from the DC promotion in Server Manager and I can authenticate to my old domain controllers to log into my domain.

However, all the SRV records for the new domain controller are missing in DNS (kerberos, ldap, gc) and I cannot use the new DC to join new clients to the domain.  I get an error that only the old comain controllers were identified by the query and that doesn't include the new DC which I am using as the target DNS to attach to the domain.

I need to be able to do this because the goal is to rebuild our system and decommission the old one including the old DCs.

I've tried running the registerdns command and restarted the netlogon service and the server itself several times.  No change.

This is migrating from one virtual zone to another and they use internal and external IP addresses so something there might be part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by demoting the domain controller, ensuring the "reister this connection's addresses in DNS" checkbox was checked, then re-promoting the domain controller.